# QApplication changing value of std::to_string

Tags: c++, qt

It seems that Qt changes the 'interpretation' of the returned string of `std::to_string(double)`.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QApplication>
#define VERSION 1.0
#define VSIZE 3

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::string version = std::to_string(VERSION).substr(0, VSIZE);
    std::cout << version << std::endl; // everything fine

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    std::cout << std::to_string(VERSION).substr(0, VSIZE); // no good
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
1.0
1,0
```

I think it's Qt because this is the thinnest example where this happens, and removing the `QApplication` declaration makes it work again. How can I fix this?

Comment: The output is different the second time around because the locale has been changed.

Comment: I tried adding this code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602136/force-point-and-not-comma-for-floating-point-in-qt but it still does't work :(

Comment: @GiovanniBerti: you tried `QLocale::setDefault(QLocale::c());` ?  Both before and after `QApplication`?  You could also try `setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");`.

Comment: What is the OS set to?

Comment: I'm on linux and the locale is "it_IT.UTF-8".

Comment: Add this line before and after the QApplication line: `std::cout << QLocale::system().name().toStdString() << std::endl;`